# Elixir / Pow Auth / ETS Cache - test raises error even if function works perfect

Tags: erlang, elixir, phoenix-framework, pow, ets

I created custom reset_password controller which works well during manual testing. Then I decided to write tests. Then problems started to appear. I read that I should mock cache and according to documentation I did step by step that configuration, but problems are not gone.

Here is my function:

```
@spec reset_password(Conn.t(), map()) :: Conn.t()
  def reset_password(conn, %{"id" => token, "user" => user_params}) do
    with {:ok, conn} <- PowResetPassword.Plug.load_user_by_token(conn, token),
         {:ok, _user, conn}  <- PowResetPassword.Plug.update_user_password(conn, user_params) do
          json(conn, %{status: "Password changed"})
    else
          {:error, _changeset, conn} ->
            json(conn, %{error: %{message: "Passwords are not the same"}})

          _ ->
            json(conn, %{error: %{message: "Expired Token"}})
    end
  end
```

And here is my reset_password test:

```
 setup do
    user =
      %User{}
        |> User.changeset(%{email: "test@example.com", password: @password, password_confirmation: @password})
        |> Repo.insert!()

    {:ok, user: user}
  end

describe "reset_password/2" do

    test "with valid token and passwords", %{conn: conn} do
      PowApiTemplate.Test.EtsCacheMock.init()
      pow_config = [otp_app: :pow_api_template]

      {:ok, %{token: token, user: user}, conn} =
        conn
        |> Pow.Plug.put_config(Application.get_env(:pow_api_template, :pow))
        |> PowResetPassword.Plug.create_reset_token(%{"email" => "test@example.com"})

      valid_params = %{"id" => token, "user" => %{"password" => @new_password, "password_confirmation" => @new_password}}

      conn = post(conn, Routes.password_path(conn, :reset_password, valid_params))

      assert json = json_response(conn, 200)
    end
  end
```

Trying to test it I got error (I also tried to put some part into setup but the same error appears or it crashes all my tests):

```
1) test reset_password/2 with valid token and passwords (PowApiTemplateWeb.PasswordControllerTest)
    test/pow_api_template_web/controllers/password_controller_test.exs:45
    ** (ArgumentError) errors were found at the given arguments:
    
      * 2nd argument: invalid options
    
    code: PowApiTemplate.Test.EtsCacheMock.init()
    stacktrace:
      (stdlib 4.0.1) :ets.new(PowApiTemplate.Test.EtsCacheMock, [:set, :protected, :named_table])
      (pow_api_template 0.1.0) test/support/ets_cache_mock.ex:5: PowApiTemplate.Test.EtsCacheMock.init/0
      test/pow_api_template_web/controllers/password_controller_test.exs:46: (test)
```

Now I am stuck. Digging through internet I cant find solution to this case. It seems that problem is with init() function, but everytime someone's occur that problem solutions were different.

There are steps I did according to posts from Pow Auth creator in other issues

I updated conn_case.ex with:

```
  setup _tags do
    EtsCacheMock.init()

    {:ok, conn: Phoenix.ConnTest.build_conn(), ets: EtsCacheMock}
  end
```

Updated test config with:

```
config :pow_api_template, :pow,
  cache_backend: [cache_store_backend: PowApiTemplate.Test.EtsCacheMock]
```

Error is the same if I change it to:

```
config :pow_api_template, :pow,
  cache_store_backend: PowApiTemplate.Test.EtsCacheMock
```

And main module

I added to test folder Ets Cache Mock:

```
defmodule PowApiTemplate.Test.EtsCacheMock do
  @moduledoc false
  @tab __MODULE__

  def init, do: :ets.new(@tab, [:ordered_set, :protected, :named_table])

  def get(config, key) do
    ets_key = ets_key(config, key)

    @tab
    |> :ets.lookup(ets_key)
    |> case do
      [{^ets_key, value} | _rest] -> value
      []                          -> :not_found
    end
  end

  def delete(config, key) do
    :ets.delete(@tab, ets_key(config, key))

    :ok
  end

  def put(config, record_or_records) do
    records     = List.wrap(record_or_records)
    ets_records = Enum.map(records, fn {key, value} ->
      {ets_key(config, key), value}
    end)

    send(self(), {:ets, :put, records, config})
    :ets.insert(@tab, ets_records)
  end

  def all(config, match) do
    ets_key_match = ets_key(config, match)

    @tab
    |> :ets.select([{{ets_key_match, :_}, [], [:"$_"]}])
    |> Enum.map(fn {[_namespace | keys], value} -> {keys, value} end)
  end

  defp ets_key(config, key) do
    [Keyword.get(config, :namespace, "cache")] ++ List.wrap(key)
  end
end
```

I dont know for now where the problems is and how to solve it. I've looking for solution for many hours two days straight and still nothing :)

Thanks for any help

Comment: Random guess: the `:ets.new` call in `EtsCacheMock` fails because the table already exists. Either catch that error, or check whether the table exists before trying to create it.

Comment: It seems that table does not exist. :ets.whereis raises :undefined for any name

Comment: I don't follow why you need to mock ETS.  Unless you're expecting data to be in the table for the tests, then you should be able to just use the real thing without a mock: it's memory; it should reset after each test run.

Comment: Function needs real token as I suppose. When I use some fake It acutally returns status 200, but with message about Expired Token. I want to assert that function shows right message about Changed Password. Problem appears during creating/passing token to the function. Solution above I found during digging but I am thinking now about just mocking result of creating token, because playing with Ets seems to be too complex for such simple test. Thanks for answer :)

Comment: When I try to  do in setup: {:ok, %{token: token, user: _user}, conn} = PowResetPassword.Plug.create_reset_token(conn, "test@example.com") And then have "real" token It raises error during test: Pow configuration not found in connection. Please use a Pow plug that puts the Pow configuration in the plug connection. What leads to absolutely nothing :D